# How to fetch the URL of the Image on upload in the CKEditor in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I want to fetch the URL of the Image on upload in the CKEditor in ASP.Net. Can anyone please tell me how can i store the URL in a string? I want the URL each time I upload a Image. I have combined CKEditor and CKFinder.

```
string urlvalue = CKEditor1.FilebrowserImageUploadUrl.ToString();
```

This returns me

```
ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Image
```

but I want only the URL of the image uploaded, like this:

```
/Novo-app-Backend/userfiles/images/Bulletin/146632_Papel-de-Parede-WebDeveloper_1280x800.jpg
```

Comment: i have combined CKEditor and CKFinder i want to fetch the URL of the Image getting Uploaded

Comment: Nobody can guess how your code is structured. Please provide the relevant code snippets so that people can help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can fetch that in .ashx file. Hope this url help you

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/423_Upload_Images_and_Integrate_with_CKeditor_in_AspNet.aspx

Comment: i have seen this URL but this is without using CKFinder is there any way with using CkFinder